# How to run benchmarking on MySQL?

Tags: asp.net, mysql, benchmarking

My server has installed MySQL Server 5.1.
I would like to run benchmarking on the MySQL, but I couldn't found sql-bench, which is Benchmark Suite provided by MySQL.

The MySQL Benchmark Suite seem like complicated to be install or setup into my server. I need one can be direct setup to test the benchmark without using Perl script liked the benchmark suite from MySQL.

Do anyone knows how to get the most popular benchmarking tool to measure MySQL performance?
I need to measure the performance of my SQL written in ASP.Net that connecting to MySQL. I need to optimize the SQL script.

It's better has a benchmarking tool where can be read my SQL in many times and return me the query result's time for comparison, etc. I just need to know the time consuming and performance for the each SQL runs in many times.

Comment: I think you may have confused "benchmarking" -- running a standard suite of queries -- with "performance" -- how your application performs.  You don't need benchmarking tools to measure your application.  Which are you measuring?  A standard benchmark application?  Your application?

Comment: I need a tool, which is similar to MySQL benchmark suite to help me measure the SQL. I can be insert value of how many times a query running, and average time about this query can be returns.

My query is not returning one row, it's running the query with joining other large table sometimes. 

I need to know how to measure the time the query runs.

Answer (score 0):

One of the Maatkit tools might help you:

[Maatkit - mk-query-profiler](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-query-profiler.html)